# Bound on Error from Censoring

Tags: normal-distribution, censoring, probability-inequalities

Suppose I have $N$ Gaussian random variables $X_1,...,X_N$ where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$. Suppose I censor each $X_i$ to lie in the range $[-t,t]$. Denote the censored values by $Z_1,...,Z_N$. I'm trying to compute the following bound: $Pr(|\sum X_i - \sum Z_i| \ge \epsilon) \le ?$ This feels like it should be an easy problem but I'm struggling how to proceed. There are several related questions about the distribution of sums of censored normal random variables which indicate the distribution is difficult to obtain in general, but I was hoping that obtaining a bound might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

We can apply standard moment-based bounds and estimates.

By choosing $\sigma$ as the unit of measurement (which replaces $t$ by $u = t/\sigma$), it suffices to work with $\sigma=1$ and then to multiply the $k^\text{th}$ moment by $\sigma^k.$

Let $\phi$ be the density of $X_i$ (which has a standard Normal distribution) and $\Phi$ be its distribution function.  For $k=0,1,2,\ldots,$ write

$$\mu(k;u) = E\left[Y_i^{k}\right] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^{k}\mathcal I(|y|\gt 0) \phi(y)\,\mathrm dy = 2\int_{-\infty}^{-u}(x+u)^{k}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

The symmetry of $Y_i$ implies $\mu(k;u)$ is the moment of order $k$ when $k$ is even and otherwise $\mu(k;u) = 0.$

We may therefore find the moments of $Y_i$ by evaluating $\mu.$  That turns out to be elementary.  Using the basic facts $\phi^\prime(x)=-x\phi(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^d \phi(x)=0$ for all $d$ (provided $u\ne 0$), an integration by parts for $k\ge 1$ gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\mu(k;u) &= 2\int_{-\infty}^{-u}(x+u)^{k}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= 2\int_{-\infty}^{-u}\left[x(x+u)^{k-1} + u(x+u)^{k-1}\right]\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= 2\int_{-u}^{-\infty}(x+u)^{k-1}(-x\phi(x))\,\mathrm dx + 2u\int_{-\infty}^{-u}(x+u)^{k-1}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= 2(k-1)\int_{-\infty}^{-u}(x+u)^{k-2}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx + u\,\mu(k-1;u)\\
&= (k-1)\mu(k-2;u) + u\,\mu(k-1;u).
\end{aligned}$$

This recursion begins by directly evaluating $\mu(0;u) = \Phi(-u)$ and $\mu(1;u) = u\Phi(-u) - \phi(-u).$  In terms of the original units of measurement, the  moment is $\sigma^{k}\mu(k;t).$  "Closed-form" solutions to this recursion are polynomials in $u$ of degree $k.$ That's no improvement over the recursion itself, which is efficient for computation.

Bounds for sums of *iid* $Y_i,$ as described in the question, can be obtained using Chebyshev's Inequality, [Markov's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), and so on.  When $N\Pr(Y\ne 0)\gg 0$ the Central Limit Theorem ought to give decent approximations.

---

To illustrate, simulations of $10^5$ independent samples with $t=\sigma$ and $t=2\sigma,$ using sample sizes $N$ sufficient to make $N\Pr(Y\ne 0) \approx 5,$ produced these distributions of the sums of the $Y_i:$

[image: Histogram and Normal QQ plots for t==1, N==16]

[image: Histogram and Normal QQ plots for t==2, N==110]

The red curves show Normal densities with variance $\mu(2,u).$  (The QQ plot shows only the first thousand values.)  Although the distribution clearly is not Normal -- it has a little too much density in the middle -- the Normal approximation is excellent in the tails.